# Copilot Neovim keybinding behave wrong?

Tags: github, shortcut, neovim, github-copilot

using copilot.vim plugin in neovim the <M+]>, <M+[> and <M+> (M stands for alt) doesn't work, the keybinding are used in insert mode and when i press alt+[ or alt+] which is the keybindings `“‘` these two characters are typed, technically its the right behavior.

if so why is keybinding that? Didn't they realize this?
I am using U.S. keyboard layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out it's not actually <kbd>Alt</kbd> key; it's <kbd>Meta</kbd> which is not set to <kbd>Alt</kbd> in mac
using iTerm2.

I set left-<kbd>Option</kbd> to <kbd>Meta</kbd> key in `Preferences` > `Profiles` > `Keys` > `General` > `Left Option key`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).